# How to improve query performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

I have a query here to update a table with the inventory type of each rep's latest inventory. However, the only way I got it to work was by using a cursor, which is really affecting performance. Below are the table declaration and query I'm using. Is there something else I can do to achieve the desired results faster?

Table:

```
create table #inv (
Rep_LName nvarchar (50),
Rep_FName nvarchar (50),
Rep_ID nvarchar (50),
Rep_Email nvarchar (100),
Rep_Status nvarchar (50),
Rep_BU nvarchar (50),
Sales_Force nvarchar (50),
Territory nvarchar (50),
Sample_Eligibility nvarchar (50),
DM_Name nvarchar (100),
Phys_Inv_Date datetime,
Last_Reconciled datetime,
Inv_Type nvarchar(50),
Days_Since_Last_inv int)
```

Query:

```
declare Inventory_type cursor 
for select rep_ID, inventory_type
from  inv_header
where rep_id in (select rep_id from #inv)
order by call_date desc
declare @rep_ID nvarchar(50)
declare @inventory_type nvarchar(50)
declare @ls_Sql as nvarchar(max)
declare @param as nvarchar(max)
select @ls_Sql=''
select @param=''
-- open cursor
open Inventory_type

fetch next from Inventory_type 
into @rep_ID, @inventory_type
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin   
    --use parameterized dynamic sql
    SET @param='@rep_ID nvarchar(50),@inventory_type nvarchar(50)'
    SET @ls_Sql='update #inv set Inv_Type = @inventory_type 
WHERE rep_id = @rep_id AND Inv_Type IS NULL'

    --pass parameter to dynamic query
    exec sp_executesql @ls_Sql,@param,@rep_ID,@Inventory_type

    fetch next from Inventory_type 
    into @rep_ID, @Inventory_type
end

close Inventory_type
deallocate Inventory_type
```

Comment: Surely you can just do this as an update statement?

Comment: RBAR alert!  (Row by agonizing row).........

Comment: Here is a learning example.....that shows a RBAR solution, and then having it refactored to a Set-Based solution.       http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/cursors-setbased-and-scalar-udf/

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use cursors; they destroy query performance. Yes, they are in the product for a reason, but they are a tool of last resort and almost always you can get the job done with a set based approach. A simple update statement will work just fine here.

```
update i 
set i.Inv_Type = h.inventory_type 
from #inv i
inner join inv_header h on i.rep_id = h.rep_id
   and h.Call_date =
   (select Max(Call_Date) 
    from inv_header i2
    where i2.rep_id = i.rep_id)
where i.inv_type is null
```

Comment: My first thought as well.

Comment: This will not get inventory_type of latest call date

Comment: @CharlesBretana Excellent point; edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  update i set 
  Inv_Type = h.inventory_type 
  From #inv i join inv_header h 
     on h.rep_id = i.Rep_ID 
        And h.Call_date =
            (Select Max(Call_Date) 
             From inv_header
             Where rep_id = i.rep_id)
  where i.Inv_Type Is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, and without knowing your database, something like this should work:

```
UPDATE #inv set Inv_Type = (SELECT inventory_type FROM inv_header
    WHERE #inv.Rep_ID = inv_header.rep_id)
    WHERE Inv_Type IS NULL
```

You could also do it as a join, might be more efficient depending on the number of rows you have.

Should get you started at least....

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants the inv_type that has the latest call date..

```
update inv
set inv.Inv_Type = ih.inventory_type
from (
    select rep_ID, max(call_date) max_call_date
    from  inv_header
    where rep_id in (select rep_id from #inv)
    group by rep_ID ) a
inner join inv_header ih 
    on ih.rep_ID = a.rep_ID
    and ih.call_date = a.max_call_date
inner join #inv inv 
    on inv.rep_ID = ih.rep_id
    and inv.Inv_Type is null
```